# mcq long table using tikz, tcolorbox or tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tabularx

I need to create similar table with different ways :

- First way using `tabular`, `tabularx`
- Second way using `Tikz`
- third way using `tcolorbox`
- how do I accomplish this? Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \sffamily
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\bfseries\centering\hsize=0.12\hsize}X| 
                              >{\centering\hsize=0.30\hsize}X| 
                              >{\hsize=0.50\hsize}X| 
                              c|
                              >{\hsize=0.10\hsize}X|}
                                                \hline
Number of question 
    &   \hfil\textbf{Question} 
        &   \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\hsize=0.5\hsize}X|}{%
            \textbf{Choose the correct answer from the four alternatives}}
                &   \hfil\textbf{Marks}     \\  \hline
\multirow{8}{*}{\Large 01} 
    & If $A=\{x\in\mathbb{C}\ :\ x^{2}=1 \}$ &  \centering $\{-1,1 \}$
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \cline{3-5}
    &and $B=\{x\in\mathbb{C}: x^{4}=1,  \}$ & \centering $\{-1,1,i,-i \}$
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \cline{3-5}
    & then $A\Delta B$ & \centering $\{-i,i \}$
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \cline{3-5}
    &        & \centering None of these
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \hline
                                                \multirow{8}{*}{\Large 02} 
    & Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a relation in the set $N$ &  reflexive and symmetric only 
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \cline{3-5}
    & of natural numbers defined bu the relattion $n\mathcal{R}m \iff n $ & symmetric and transitive only 
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \cline{3-5}
    & is a factor of $ m $ & reflexive and transitive only 
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \cline{3-5}
    &  The relation $\mathcal{R} is $      & \centering and equivalence relation
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produced [image]

but i need someone to fix it to looks like good

- centered cell
- one big cell for each question attached to four statement row as my second photo

Comment: Please make your NWE compilable. Missing is `\begin{document}` and table is very unusual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \sffamily
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\bfseries\centering\hsize=0.12\hsize}X| 
                              >{\hsize=0.20\hsize}X| 
                              >{\hsize=0.45\hsize}X| 
                              c|
                              >{\hsize=0.20\hsize}X|}
                                                \hline
Number of question 
    &   \hfil\textbf{Question} 
        &   \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\hsize=0.5\hsize}X|}{%
            \textbf{Choose the correct answer from the four alternatives}}
                &   \hfil\textbf{Marks}     \\  \hline
\multirow{8}{*}{\Large 01} 
    & statement A & A statement 1 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \cline{2-5}
    & statement B & A statement 2 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \cline{2-5}
    & statement C & A statement 3 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \cline{2-5}
    & statement D & A statement 4 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Your code (in the first version) has many serious problems:

- The `\begin{document}` and `\end{center}` were missing
- number of declared and used columns aren't in accordance
- use `\hline` inside cell is forbidden
- even empty cell had to to start with ampersand

**Addendum:**
I guess that now you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

In code are marked lines which are new or changed. This should help yopu to understand the code below. Note: this will work if you have instaled recent `multirow` package (old one doesnt define `=` option)!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \sffamily
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}% <-- added
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}% <-- added
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\bfseries\centering\hsize=0.12\hsize}X|
                              >{\centering\hsize=0.47\hsize}X|% <-- changed
                              >{\centering\hsize=0.33\hsize}X|% <-- changed
                              >{\centering\hsize=0.02\hsize}X|% <-- changed
                              >{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.07\hsize}X|}% <-- changed
                                                        \hline
Number of question
    &   \textbf{Question}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\hsize=0.35\hsize}X|}{%
            \textbf{Choose the correct answer from the four alternatives}}
                &   \textbf{Marks}                      \\  \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\Large 01}% <-- changed number of lines
    &   \multirow{4}{=}{% <-- added
        If $A=\{x\in\mathbb{C}\ :\ x^{2}=1 \}$
        and $B=\{x\in\mathbb{C}: x^{4}=1,  \}$
        then $A\Delta B$}
        &  $\{-1,1 \}$                  & $\square$ &   \\  \cline{3-5}
    &   &  $\{-1,1,i,-i \}$             & $\square$ &   \\  \cline{3-5}
    &   & $\{-i,i \}$                   & $\square$ &   \\  \cline{3-5}
    &   & None of these                 & $\square$ &   \\  \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\Large 02}% <-- changed number of lines
    &   \multirow{3}{=}{% <-- added
        Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a relation in the set $N$
        is a factor of $m$ reflexive and transitive only
        of natural numbers defined but the relation $n\mathcal{R}m \iff n $, then
        the relation $\mathcal{R}$ is:}
        & reflexive and symmetric only  & $\square$ &   \\  \cline{3-5}
    &   & symmetric and transitive only & $\square$ &   \\  \cline{3-5}
    &   & and equivalence relation      & $\square$ &   \\  \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I kindly ask you that you finish now with new asks in the same question and for any further improvements/wishes etc ask new question. Recent request is actually new question ...

Comment: i appreciate your help could you make it with 'tcolorbox'

Comment: and where the `tcolorbox` should be? around the table? in documentation for `tcolorbox` are on page 66 nice example about how to integrate `tcolorbox` and `tabularx`. please, edit your question and clarify, what you like to obtain. on this way more people will see your problem and will be able to help you.

Comment: Shouldn't the 1st `X` column be specifies as `> {\hsize=0.15\hsize}`?

Comment: @Zarko yes i would like it to be around  the table please

Comment: @Bernard, I expect this, but then result is worse. Now I reduce it to `>{\hsize=0.12\hsize}` and obtain better result: `\hline`s don't protrude right table border anymore. Why this happen, I didn't figured out yet.

Comment: @Educ, please edit your question and add your comment there (or ask new question). Then more people will see, what you like to obtain. As question is stated now, my answer fulfill all request in it :-)

Comment: @Zarko: Maybe this is linked that `\multicolumn`s that come across `X` columns should be avoided.

Comment: Meanwhile I write new answer. See, if it provide what you like to achieve.

Comment: acually you forgot to add cell check my photo again please

Comment: stament A + stament B+stament c+statment D should be in one cell contains question bla bla bla

Comment: as base I use your code. in it this is not presented. this change you can do yourself, for exercise. my MWE provide table format as it is on your image. so you have a frame for table. frankly said, content of table is up to you. it is simple change cell content.

Comment: dude frankly i don't know how to do it

Comment: than please add to your question image of what you like to have. from your comment i'm not able to figured out this (my crystal ball is foggy today ...)

Answer (score 4):

With your comment and edition of question you actually ask new question ... let me be allowed to write new answer :-)

Based on example of integration `tabularx` and `tcolorbox` on page 66 of manual for package **tcolorbox**, version 3.59 from 2016/10/21):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{enhanced,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\large\sffamily,
        fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
        colback=yellow!10!white, colframe=red!50!black,
        colbacktitle=Salmon!30!white,
        coltitle=black, center title}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={|>{\bfseries\centering\hsize=0.12\hsize}X| 
                              >{\hsize=0.20\hsize}X| 
                              >{\hsize=0.45\hsize}X| 
                              c|
                              >{\hsize=0.20\hsize}X|},
                  title=My table]  
Number of question 
    &   \hfil\textbf{Question} 
        &   \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\hsize=0.5\hsize}X|}{%
            \textbf{Choose the correct answer from the four alternatives}}
                &   \hfil\textbf{Marks}          \\  \hline
\multirow{8}{*}{\Large 01} 
    & statement A & A statement 1 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \cline{2-5}
    & statement B & A statement 2 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \cline{2-5}
    & statement C & A statement 3 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \cline{2-5}
    & statement D & A statement 4 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                        & \fbox{}   &       \\  \hline
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if you liked solution, you can vote for it or even accept it :-)